# Why can't I find Sequential in TensorFlow (julia)?

Tags: tensorflow, julia

```
julia> using TensorFlow

julia> tf= TensorFlow
TensorFlow

julia> m = tf.Sequential()
```

Tried using above code getting this error

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: Sequential not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./Base.jl:26
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[3]:1
```